# Does HTTP 1.0 request serves chunked responses in play framework 2.2.1

Tags: nginx, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have used the sample app-eventSource of play-2.2.1 to develop a feed server. It is working fine. But as soon as I am running the application behind a proxy server nginx, I am getting:
The response to this request is chunked and hence requires HTTP 1.1 to be sent, but this is a HTTP 1.0 request.Is my proxy server converting the request to HTTP 1.0? Please help how to resolve this...Is it possible from application point of view to resolve this...or can nginx update solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Exactly the same problem has been solved here: [Lighttpd reverse proxy converts HTTP/1.1 requests to 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677776/lighttpd-reverse-proxy-converts-http-1-1-requests-to-1-0)

I fixed the problem with Play using the following code:

```
location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;    
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```